# Why is vkCreateDevice() crashing on Android 11?

Tags: android, android-ndk, vulkan

I have a small Vulkan app (all it does is draw a triangle) that worked on my Samsung S10 with Android 10 for months. But yesterday the phone updated to Android 11 and now my app crashes on startup when calling 'vkCreateDevice()'.

I don't see anything wrong with any of the parameters, and again this works on Android 10 devices.  How do I determine what is wrong?  Has anyone else encountered this issue?